# Convert Spring configuration from XML to Java-based: No Qualifying bean Exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-ws

I have a Spring configuration in XML:

```
<bean id="webServiceTemplate" class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate">
    <property name="marshaller" ref="marshaller" />
    <property name="unmarshaller" ref="unmarshaller" />
    <property name="messageSender">
        <bean class="org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpComponentsMessageSender">
            <property name="connectionTimeout" value="30000" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I tried to switch to Java-based configuration, but I got the error "No Qualifying Bean of type WebServiceTemplate Found". How can I fix it?

```
@Bean
public HttpComponentsMessageSender httpComponentsMessageSender() {
    HttpComponentsMessageSender messageSender = new HttpComponentsMessageSender();
    messageSender.setConnectionTimeout(30000);
    return messageSender;
}

@Bean
public WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate(WebServiceTemplate template) {
    template.setMessageSender(httpComponentsMessageSender());
    return template;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `WebServiceTemplate` as an argument in the `@Bean` method, so Spring assumes you have a bean of that type already created somewhere else. You don't, and Spring goes down screaming about non-existent beans.

You need to instantiate it yourself, just like you did `HttpComponentsMessageSender`:

```
@Bean
public WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate() {
    WebServiceTemplate template = new WebServiceTemplate();
    template.setMessageSender(httpComponentsMessageSender());
    return template;
}
```

Comment: Thank You. That Solved it. But it looks like the timeout thing doesnot work. It doesnot timeout in 30 secs. Can you please help me on that with some tips if you can? :)